# How is dynamodb's range/sort key stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know the data structure of dynamodb's range/sort key? I am about to massive data into 25 hashkey with sorkey, with each parition having a lot of data.

I try looking everywhere to find how the range/sort key is organized but can't seem to find an answer. Ideally I hope it is efficiently organized, maybe a b-tree.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the link, I've read the page before, but this time I spotted the answer.

> DynamoDB then scans the sort key attribute values until it finds Fido.

That's terrible.

Comment: It's not "terrible" - it's scanning sort key attributes from a tightly clustered set of data. From my experience with LevelDB (I wrote the book) and working at Realm, column-stores can do insanely fast linear scans within ranges. In contrast, a b-tree requires reading a lot of scattered data as you traverse it. It's non-intuitive. Also, scanning a column with similar data (eg: prefixed) allows for compression.

Comment: Looking at the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html

*However, it stores all the items with the same partition key value physically close together, ordered by sort key value.*

How exactly does it achieve this though? If a new item is inserted into the center of the sorted list, doesn't it then have to move half of the items forward one step?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but thought of posting this anyways to clear the wrong assumptions that DynamoDB scans a partition as the search algorithm.

As described from a blog post from Alex DeBrie, a well established AWS Data Hero: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/single-table-vs-multi-table-design-in-amazon-dynamodb/

> DynamoDB stores the items on each partition in a B-tree that are ordered according to their partition key and (if used by the table) sort key. This B-tree provides logarithmic time complexity for finding a key. This use of a B-tree on subsets of your data allows for highly efficient range queries of items with the same partition key